# What is the difference between Leloir and Non-Leloir glucosyl transferases?

Tags: enzymes, biotechnology

The following questions were on the slides for my biotech course and I haven't been able to find any information on what the answer is.

What is the difference between Leloir and Non-Leloir glucosyl transferases?

Answer (score 1):

LeLoir glucosyltransferases use uridine-diphosphate (UDP) 'activated' sugars as substrate, for example [UDP-glucose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uridine_diphosphate_glucose), where 'LeLoir' refers to the [LeLoir pathway](https://faseb.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1096/fasebj.10.4.8647345), the metabolic pathway that inter-converts glucose and galactose (or, more strictly, the inter-conversion of UDP-glucose and UDP-galactose)

Non-LeLoir glucosyltranserases use *sucrose* as substrate and *do not require the sugar to be be conjugated to UDP* (or to be 'activated' in any way), and as such are very useful in the biotechnology industry.

See

[A new pathway for the synthesis of oligosaccharides by the use of non-Leloir glycosyltransferases](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10242420500538274))

---

[LeLoir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Federico_Leloir) was an eminent Argentinian biochemist.

For the enzymes of the LeLoir pathway,

[The Leloir pathway: a mechanistic imperative for three enzymes to change the stereochemical configuration of a single carbon in galactose](https://faseb.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1096/fasebj.10.4.8647345)

by [Perry A Frey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_A._Frey) is IMO definitive (and the pdf is freely available).

(Glucose and galactose are epimers: they differ only by the configuratation at C4. A key enzyme of the LeLoir pathway is UDP-glucose 4-epimerase, which contains a tightly bound NAD(+) and epimerization proceeds by oxidation/reduction (strictly, hydride abstraction/addition) at C-4, where the tightly bound NAD(+) is transiently reduced during catalysis: ie, NAD acts a (transient) hydride 'repository'! To the best of my knowledge, no enzyme has ever been found that *directly* catalyses the epimerization of glucose to galactose (although there appears to be no thermodynamic reason why this is not possible): the sugar must be conjugated to UDP in order to be a substrate for UDP-glucose 4-epimerase)